# How to get the client side post size?

Tags: javascript, php, handsontable

I want to ask that how can I get the size of data I am passing as a client to the server.As while developing an application, I am unable to get the whole data on server side.My POST limit size at the server side is 6M as in php.ini file.

I have asked a similar question earlier([How to parse large data via POST query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581331/how-to-parse-large-data-via-post-query?noredirect=1#comment78147038_45581331)), but didn't get a prompt answer.

Thanks

Comment: then increase the post limit size to 22m in php.ini

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)

Comment: my (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']= 3598 and post_max_size in php.ini =6M .So , is it justified that i am not getting full data i am parsing?

Comment: you have not described the problem (i.e. what is it that is not working) but rather your assumption as to its root cause.  C'mon, cought it up : how is this not working, and how do you assert the incorrect behaviour.

Comment: It is not working coz when i alert the datastring i am sending to server,i can see all the stuff i am sending.But at the server side when i  alert the maker , i.e the last key-value pair of datastring , i am getting that, but i am not getting the $all_data which contains the data in the rows of the handsontable on the front-end , that the user has entered.

Comment: ah ... u just went over to your other question.  You are sending this on the url, and 3598 maybe larger than you can handle in your browser, see **[this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458445/what-is-a-safe-maximum-length-a-segment-in-a-url-path-should-be)**. Try to post that as json in the body of the request.

Comment: What does "try to post as json" mean , as you can see in my post(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581331/how-to-parse-large-data-via-post-query?noredirect=1#comment78147038_45581331) , i have used json.stringify.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data_size = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
```

Comment: using this i am getting 3598 and max_post_size= 6M , then i should'nt have face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this function on submit form

```
<button onclick="store()" type="button">form submit</button>

function store(){     
    var totalsize = 0;    // total post data size
    $('form').find('input[type=file]').each(function() { // for all files in form
        totalsize += this.files[0].size;
    });

    totalsize=totalsize+($("form").not("[type='file']").serialize().length);

    if (totalsize > (6 * 1048576)) { // > 6MB   
        // this will exceed post_max_size PHP setting, now handle...

        alert('this will exceed post_max_size PHP setting')
    } else if ($('form').find('input[type=file]').length >= 10) { // max_file_upload_limit = 10; 
        // if file upload is more than 10
         alert('upload is more than 10 files')
    }else{

      you are free upload data successfully
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not uploading a file but rows of handson table .Please see my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581331/how-to-parse-large-data-via-post-query?noredirect=1#comment78147038_45581331